# placeholder for schema's name in Pl/Sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a simple `Pl/Sql` body as following:

```
begin 
  ------------------- deletes -------------------------       
  delete from ticket.KC4ENTKEY where  KC2ENTID200 in ('ETICKET');

  ------------------- inserts -------------------------       
  insert into host.kc4achmap(kc4srl467,kc4hst468,kc4id455)
              values('AUTHENTICATION',1,'TICKET');
end;
```

I may do change schema names for sample , `ticket` schema may changes to `ticket_2`.
My question is : What can I set a parameter or placeholder for schema names (for removing hard coded schema's name)?

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a placeholder for schema names (or table or column names), because Oracle checks at compile time if the schema/table/column exists and if you have access to it.

To add flexibility, you can add a layer of indirection via synonyms or views:

```
CREATE SYNONYM my_kc4entkey FOR ticket.kc4entkey;
CREATE SYNONYM my_kc4achmap FOR host.kc4achmap;
```

In your code, you'd refer to the synonym instead of the fully qualified table:

```
begin
  delete from my_kc4entkey where kc2entid200 in ('ETICKET');
  insert into my_kc4achmap(kc4srl467,kc4hst468,kc4id455) values('AUTHENTICATION',1,'TICKET'); 
end;
```

If you need to change the schema name later on, you'll just need to change the synonym and leave your code unchanged:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM my_kc4entkey FOR ticket2.kc4entkey;
```